# Сделать ссылку для скачивания изображения с сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как в html или php сделать ссылку на скачивание изображения с сайта. То есть что бы при нажатии на ссылку открывалось окошко браузера c предложением сохранить файл. Нужен самый простой и надёжный способ, который будет работать во всех новых браузерах.

Answer (score 3):

Ссылка такого вида:

```
<a href="download.php?file=arrow.png">Скачать картинку</a>
```

А там:

```
<?php

$filename = '';
if (isset($_GET['file'])) $filename = $_GET['file'];

if (file_exists($filename)) {
        header("Content-type: application/x-download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        readfile($filename);
} else { header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); echo '404 Not Found'; }

?>
```

Comment: а в каких местах имя файла прописывать?

Comment: В ссылке: <a href="download.php?file=ВОТ_ТУТ_ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА">Скачать картинку</a>